# My for loop is not incrementing

Tags: java, android, arraylist

So I have an `Arraylist` containing `Strings` which are urls, I am then parsing these strings into an ImageLoader.. My problem is that the `int` in the loop doesn't seem to be incrementing, however I know the loop is looping because I get the same output the same number of times as the size of the `Arraylist`.

Here is the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < AsyncDownloader.imageList.size(); i++) {

        String imageUrl = AsyncDownloader.imageList.get(i);
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(1080, 440));
        imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(false);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);

        Log.i(TAG, "Check? " + i);
        imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrl, imageView, options);
        return imageView;
    }
```

Debug Log:

`02-25 11:30:27.584    7299-7299/my.app I/Debug﹕ Check? 0
02-25 11:30:27.594    7299-7299/my.app I/Debug﹕ Check? 0
02-25 11:30:27.614    7299-7299/my.app I/Debug﹕ Check? 0
02-25 11:30:27.744    7299-7299/my.app I/Debug﹕ Check? 0...`

I've tried using a `ListIterator` but that seems to give me the same output and i've tried placing `i++` within the loop so it gets run but then I get the same the same output but with the index of 1.

I also know that it's not the contents of the `ArrayList` because I am also logging that beforehand to check when downloading urls.

I have looked at similar questions however they all seemed to have a problem within their code and the code I already have here has been suggested as the fix.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "however I know the loop is looping" - it's not really. You're unconditionally returning from the first iteration of the loop. My guess is that you're looping in the *calling* code, but you haven't shown us that.

Comment: You are returning a value after one iteration !!!

Comment: return statement is reason.

Comment: `  return imageView; ` because of this control is going out of method without increment the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is in

```
return imageView;
```

you can remove it from inside the loop. and do as below

```
List<imageView> listOfImages = new ArrayList<imageView>();
for (int i = 0; i < AsyncDownloader.imageList.size(); i++) {
// leave your code as it is..
// before return statement just write this one
listOfImages.add(imageView);
// remove return statement from inside the loop

}
// after loop you can return listOfImages arraylist of imageview

return listOfImages;
```

Comment: Okay, i will try this now and let you know how it goes :)

Comment: So i've just tried what you suggested but because it's an extension of the `BaseAdapter` class,  and this is in the `getView` method, it doesn't allow for a return of this `List` and trying to cast to `ImageView` throws and error on running the app. I appreciate your help by the way

Comment: what is return type for this method??

Comment: then you can not use arraylist. you have to come up with other solution

Answer (score 6):

```
return imageView;
```

At this point you are leaving the method without continuing the loop.

Comment: Ah i see, that makes sense.. But then how can i return the imageView and still get the loop to loop?

Comment: You can't do both of that thing

Comment: @AaronD that depends on your requirement and design

Comment: @Prashant Requirement: Load images from 179 urls which are gathered from an external XML and stored in an Arraylist. Does this help? Sorry if i seem like i don't know what i'm doing, i'm trying to develop this app for my company without ever touching Java before :/

Answer (score 4):

```
return imageView;
```

So, your loop is executed only once, with `i = 0`.